# Hard Big O complexity for 3 loops

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, nested-loops, code-analysis

I try to calculate Big O complexity for this code but I always fail....

I tried to nest SUM's or to get the number of steps for each case like:

- i=1 j=1 k=1 (1 step)
- i=2 j=1,2 k=1,2,3,4 (4 steps)
- . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
- i=n (i said n = 2^(log n) j = 1,2,4,8,16,.....,n k=1,2,3,4,.....n^2 (n^2 steps)

then sum all the steps together, I need help.

```
for (int i=1; i<=n; i*=2)

   for (int j=1; j<=i; j*=2)

      for(int k=1; k<=j*j; k++)

           //code line with complexity code O(1)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical programming but rather belongs on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't think this is O(1). Just the outer two loops are nlogn

Comment: @MadPhysicist  OP is saying the code _inside_ the innermost loop is arbitrary with complexity O(1)

Comment: @BenJones you are right about O(1) i put it there instead of a code line that is equal with O(1) complexity

Comment: @Ben. Got it. Answer holds with minor edit.

Comment: @RaresAndrei. Do you have an answer key? (I am assuming this is from an assignment or similar). I'm just wondering because O(n^2) is O((nlogn)^2), but provides a more useful bound. I'm curious to see if there's a flaw in my last answer.

Comment: @Ben. My answer was BS so I posted another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at the number of times the inner loop runs: `j2`. But `j` steps along in powers of 2 up to `i`. `i` in turn steps in powers of 2 up to `n`. So let's "draw" a little graphic of the terms of the sum that would give us the total number of iterations:

```
  ---- 1
   ^   1 4
   |   1 4 16
log2(n)   ...
   |   1 4 16 ... n2/16
   v   1 4 16 ... n2/16 n2/4
  ---- 1 4 16 ... n2/16 n2/4 n2
       |<------log2(n)------>|
```

The graphic can be interpreted as follows: each value of `i` corresponds to a row. Each value of `j` is a column within that row. The number itself is the number of iterations `k` goes through. The values of `j` are the square roots of the numbers. The values of `i` are the square roots of the last element in each row. The sum of all the numbers is the total number of iterations.

Looking at the bottom row, the terms of the sum are `(2z)2 = 22z` for `z = 1 ... log2(n)`. The number of times that the terms appear in the sum is modulated by the height of the column. The height for a given term is `log2(n) + 1 - z` (basically a count down from `log2(n)`).

So the final sum is

```
log2(n)
  Σ  22z(log2(n) + 1 - z)
 z = 1
```

Here is what Wolfram Alpha has to say about evaluating the sum: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28%28log%5B2%2C+n%5D%29+%2B+1+-+z%29%282%5E%282z%29%29%2C+z%3D1+to+log%5B2%2C+n%5D:

```
C1n2 - C2log(n) - C3
```

Cutting out all the less significant terms and constants, the result is

```
O(n2)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
For the outermost loop:

  sum_{i in {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...}} 1, i <= n (+)

  <=>

  sum_{i in {2^0, 2^1, 2^2, ... }} 1, i <= n

Let 2^I = i:

  2^I = i <=> e^{I log 2} = i <=> I log 2 = log i <=> I = (log i)/(log 2)

Thus, (+) is equivalent to

  sum_{I in {0, 1, ... }} 1, I <= floor((log n)/(log 2)) ~= log n                      (*)
```

---

```
Second outermost loop:

  sum_{j in {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ...}} 1, j <= i (++)

As above, 2^I = i, and let 2^J = j. Similarly to above,
(++) is equivalent to:

  sum_{J in {0, 1, ... }} 1, J <= floor((log (2^I))/(log 2)) = floor(I/(log 2)) ~= I   (**)
```

---

```
To touch base, only the outermost and second outermost
have now been reduced to

  sum_{I in {0, 1, ... }}^{log n} sum_{J in {0, 1, ...}}^{I} ...

Which is (if there would be no innermost loop) O((log n)^2)
```

---

```
Innermost loop is a trivial one if we can express the largest bound in terms of `n`.

  sum_{k in {1, 2, 3, 4, ...}} 1, k <= j^2 (+)

As above, let 2^J = j and note that j^2 = 2^(2J)

  sum_{k in {1, 2, 3, 4, ...}} 1, k <= 2^(2J)

Thus, k is bounded by 2^(2 max(J)) = 2^(2 max(I)) = 2^(2 log(n) ) = 2n^2                (***)
```

---

Combining `(*)`, `(**)` and `(***)`, the asymptotic complexity of the three nested loops is:

- `O(n^2 log^2 n)` (or, `O((n log n)^2)`).

Comment: I've replaced my answer with something more convincing

Comment: This is _an_ upper bound, but if @MadPhysicist's reasoning is correct (which it seems to be), then this is not the tightest upper bound we can get.

Comment: @BenJones I'll take the time some day (not today) to perform a rigorous analysis using sigma notation, to find what is actually the tightest asymptotic bound.